# Spark Driver High CPU

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I've been using Spark for a few months on Databricks and recently decided to spin up my own cluster over GCP for debugging purposes.
I wish to run the Spark driver from within PyCharm and have it submit tasks to a remote cluster.

Here's what I did:

1. Created about 5 GCE instances
2. Created a bridged VPN between my office and the instances.
3. Set `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` to the IP of the VPN interface and `SPARK_MASTER_IP` to the IP of the master's VPN interface on each node.
4. started the master and slaves in standalone mode with start-master.sh and start-slaves.sh
5. Created a run configuration in PyCharm and added the following environment variables:

   - `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` - The IP of the VPN interface on my laptop
   - `SPARK_MASTER` - spark://{master VPN IP}:7077
   - `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` - "*--driver-java-options \'-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m\' --driver-memory 4G --jars "local:/opt/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar,local:/opt/spark/jars/commons-csv-1.1.jar,local:/opt/spark/jars/jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar,local:/opt/spark/jars/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar,local:/opt/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.6.0.jar,local:/opt/spark/jars/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar,local:/opt/spark/jars/spark-csv_2.10-1.2.0.jar" --py-files my_egg pyspark-shell*"
   - `SPARK_HOME` - /opt/spark (where spark is located on every node as well as the driver)

After seeing that worked nicely I attempted to load a textFile from S3, here's a snippet:

```
sc = SparkContext(os.environ['SPARK_MASTER'], 'RemoteDebugger')
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
rdd = sc.textFile('s3a://{some_path}')
rdd.count()
```

A few seconds after I run this my laptop goes bananas and uses 100% CPU on all of my cores as well as 100% RAM.
The file is only 66MB large.
The last log message I'm seeing is:

> INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1

Does anyone have an explanation as to why this happens?

Comment: After further investigation, I found out it has something to do with the S3 communication. when loading a local file or a file from GCS it works fine

Comment: Facing similar issue on spark streaming on AWS.. Can you please explain how you solved it..?